# Collect details of java threads in a REDHAT Linux server

Tags: java, linux, redhat, java-threads

I need to collect details of java threads in a REDHAT Linux server but i cannot use JDK or update the java because the applications requisites a specific version. Java running on linux server is 1.6.0_45.

They are consuming a lot of memory and CPU

Some advises to get these Thread details using only Linux commands? Thank you.

Comment: Check if there is a signal you Can send the process to create a thread dump

Comment: Hi ThorBjorn, thank you for your reply, =) Can you tell more more about "signals"? How can I use this for get the thread dump?

Comment: Are you talking about kill -3 <pid>? I tried but i didn't find this thread dump in no one folder.

Comment: The thread dump goes to the standard output of the JVM process.

Comment: Java 1.6.0_45 is horribly out of date.  Java 6 was EOL on 2013-04-16.  That is 7 years of security patches, performance updates, etc that you are running.

Comment: @StephenC isn’t it quite clear this is a very legacy system.

Comment: Yes.  It is clear to you and me.  But it is not necessarily clear to the OP just how close to a black hole this system is.